# Is there a function in Haskell that is the opposite of the ord function in Data.Char

Tags: haskell

i.e. it takes an Int and returns the corresponding Char for that Int i.e. 75 would return 'K'?

Comment: Note that `chr` is `toEnum`, and `ord` is `fromEnum`.  (Specialized)

Answer (score 10):

The answer to this question is `chr` as others have pointed out.

Frequently questions like this, "Does there exist a function `Int -> Char`?" can be quickly answered using [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/).

Searching hoogle for `Int -> Char` lists `chr` as the top match: http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Int+-%3E+Char

Furthermore, in most browsers you can customize the address bar so that you can quickly search from your browser. In Chrome, go to Settings, "Manage search engines...", scroll to the bottom of the list and add "hoogle", "h",  and "http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%s" as an entry. Then you can go to the address bar, type "h Int -> Char" and it will take you to the results.

Answer (score 8):

You're looking for the `chr` function in `Data.Char`

```
> :m Data.Char
> chr 75
'K'
```